# Cannot clone the data

Tags: java, object, clone, cloning

I need to give the input as only name which is in the WorkflowCloneRequestDTO  class and all the instances need to be copied by their own. I'm trying to post the name from the postman and the id through the url which already exists.

But the data is not cloning. I'm not understanding where the problem is

This is the controller class:

```
@PostMapping("{id}/duplicate")
    @ResponseBody
    public WorkflowViewDTO duplicateWorkFlow(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody @Valid WorkflowCloneRequestDTO cloneRequest, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            throw new ControllerException(bindingResult, Constants.INPUT_VALIDATION_ERROR);
        }
    return workFlowService.cloneWorkflow(id, cloneRequest);
}
```

This the service class:

```
public WorkflowViewDTO cloneWorkflow(Long id, WorkflowCloneRequestDTO workflowCloneRequestDTO) {
        Workflow workflow = workflowDAO.findById(id);
        if (workflow == null) throw new ServiceException(ErrorEnum.WORKFLOW_NOT_FOUND);
        Workflow duplicateWorkFlow = SerializationUtils.clone(workflow);
        duplicateWorkFlow.setId(null);
        //duplicateWorkFlow.setId(null);
        duplicateWorkFlow.setName(workflowCloneRequestDTO.getName());
        duplicateWorkFlow.setIsActive(true);
        duplicateWorkFlow = workflowDAO.save(duplicateWorkFlow);
        return duplicateWorkFlow.getView(WorkflowViewDTO.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should reconsider using `SerializationUtils.clone` at all. This is a slow way to copy data, and it looks like you do not need a copy outside of `cloneWorkflow`.

If you really need a copy, consider creating a copy constructor for `Workflow` or use setters and getters to extract necessary data.

Comment: I've changed SerializationUtils.clone to org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.clone and created getters and setters for all the classes which I'm using. Still cannot able to clone the data

Comment: Perhaps you do not need to make a clone at all?

Comment: Make sure `workflowDAO.findById(id)` returns a valid object before trying to clone it.